# Free Software for Partition Manager

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista

Free Software for the Partition Manager on Windows XP/vista?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).  You can create a Boot CD and use that to work with partitions.

Comment: I love GParted. Helped me when no other tool would.

Answer (score 6):

Windows Vista now has a built in partition manager. You can access it like this:

1. Go to **Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Computer Management**.
2. Then go down to **Storage / Disk Management**. That brings up your drives.
3. Now you can just **select a partition within a drive.**
4. **Right click it** and you'll have options to **Shrink**, **Extend** or **Delete** it. The former two show a popup detailing what size you'd like.

More [info here](http://www.vistarewired.com/2007/02/16/how-to-resize-a-partition-in-windows-vista).

Answer (score 3):

[Easeus Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) is an excellent tool, and the Home version is free!  It has a bunch of useful features.  I've been using it for a little while, and still cannot believe they give it away for free.  You should definitely try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Parted Magic is pretty easy to use, and free

http://partedmagic.com/

Comment: Far superior to GParted IMHO. Sooooo many tools *drool*.

Answer (score 1):

[Cue Partition Manager](http://www.cutepm.com/) is a very basic windows solution that is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Paragon Drive Backup 9.0 Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/db-express/download.html) - You can do almost everything with this free edition

Answer (score 1):

[System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) has a nice GUI (type startx after you boot) to manage your partitions. You need to simply boot the CD and then select the partition manager.