# Windows 2008 partitioning tool?

Tags: partitioning, windows-server-2008, software-rec, partition-magic

As on Windows 2008 the Partition Magic does not seems to work anymore, is there any other tool similar ?

Comment: By Windows 2008 do you mean Windows Server 2008 (R2)?? Can you clarify?

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/questions/12386 http://superuser.com/questions/13943

Answer (score 2):

What do you wish to accomplish? Windows 2008 now has quite a built already built-in.

Fire up Server Manager, expand Storage and start Disk Management. You can shrink and grow volumes there just by right-clicking on them.

Answer (score 1):

There are other partitioning programs.  I've used partition commander.  You can also use Linux live CDs as most of them have the gparted (GUI based) partitioning tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Diskpart which ships with Windows 2008. There may be a possibility you may not be able to perform certain partitioning tasks within the Server 2008 running.

I would suggest boot the system with the Windows PE 2.0/3.0 disk. Then use Diskpart and you can create/delete/shrink/expand partitions etc. The only thing is that Diskpart is commandline.